# Attachment format issue in Power Automate "When a new email arrives (V3)"

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-platform

I am facing an issue in a Power automate workflow which the task is to get the user name from the subject of any email which arrives into inbox which the subject should be as "Welcome name surname". with an "attachment included" feature as well. And this will add that particular email subject name into a SharePoint list finally. This WF uses the feature "When a new email arrives (V3)" which checks the particular email subject as well as it checks if there is an attachment as well. However this works for usual "Outlook Attachments", but not to attachments as "VCF" files. Means the SharePoint list updated with the email subject user name for the email with an attachment as "Outlook Attachments". But the SP list didn't get updated when i received the email with an attachment as a VCF files. Does someone knows if this is an issue with the Power Automate action "When a new email arrives (V3)" or not?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You haven’t described the problem. What exactly is the issue with VCF files?

Comment: I am using the action "When a new email arrives (V3)" in a Power Automate workflow to trigger email incomings to MS Outlook inbox. So here I am checking "attachment included" field as well. Which means there should be an attachment as well. And also I am checking the Email subject as well (Ex: Welcome John Doe) and split the name part only from that Welcome subject line and update a SharePoint list with that name only. However this workflow runs fine and update the SP list for the file format "Outlooks  Attachment". But the SP list did not update for the file attachment format VCF.

Comment: So i want to know if this "When a new email arrives (V3)" in PA has issues with VCF file formats?

Comment: Show us the email and then show us the resulting trigger in the flow.  There's no reason for it to have some specific issue with VCF files, it's just an attachment.  If it's in the email, it would be in the trigger data.